# Function and method in Scala

Tags: scala

What are the practical differences between a function and a method in Scala? I am only trying to build a list of practical differences, which I didn't readily find in the other entry talking about functions and methods in Scala.

So far, I have found that:

1. functions cannot have default values for their parameters but methods can,
2. functions can be anonymous, but methods always have a name,
3. methods can be type-parameterized, but functions can't.

Any other real difference?

Also, what is going on here? The types of both objects seem to be the same?

```
scala> val f = (x: Int) => x + 1
f: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1097/560897187@75120e58

scala> :t f
Int => Int

scala> def g = (x: Int) => x + 1
g: Int => Int

scala> :t g
Int => Int
```

Comment: What you have there is two functions, not a function and a method

Comment: @puhlen - I thought `def` was the marker of methods - is that not the case?

Comment: @ggovan - I created this entry after seeing the one you reference because I felt the other entry was not all that clear from a practical point of view.

Comment: @Frank more specifically, you have a method that takes no arguments returns a function that takes an int and returns and int.  If you just wanted to implement it as a method that takes an int and returns an it it would look like `def h(x: Int) = x + 1`

Comment: @puhlen - got it. Thanks.

Comment: You can add the difference in `return` behavior to your list, as described in one of the answers to the referenced post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2529905/5344058; Altogether, this still seems like a duplicate to me.